# Unequal number of repeated measure for random factor and lmer

Tags: mixed-model, linear

I'm doing a linear mixed model such as:

```
model1<-lmer(Y~factor(X1)*X2+(1|species))
```

as I have repeated measures of the triplet (Y,X1,X2) per species depending on X1 (i.e. one couple of values (Y,X2) per modality of the factor X1).

### My problems are both:

- is it a problem that the number of repeated measures per species is not balanced ?
- For some species, I have no repeated measure (only one couple of data (Y,X2) for a given modality of X1. Is it a problem ?

Actually my model summary reports a variance and standard deviation for the random factor equal to 0. I guess something is wrong or mispecified but I don't know why a part if the answers to both of my questions is "YES".

If "YES" are the answer how to deal with this particular design ?

Thanks for you help

Comment: Showing a piece or, better, a summary of the data may help to answer you questions.

Comment: Oh yes sorry @utobi. This is a small dataset. Here is the summary of my data. The factor 'species' has 18 modalities from whose 3 are repeated 3 times, 6 are repeated 2 times, and 9 are repeated only once. The Y and X2 are continuous variable, and the factor X1 has 3 modalities. The final sample size is 30 rows

Answer (score 2):

Mixed models, in general, work with unbalanced data. With that being said however, you should also consider why you have fewer measurements for some species. This links to missing data issues, in which case the mixed model, if correctly specified, provides valid inferences under the missing completely at random and missing at random mechanisms.

With regard to the variance that is estimated to be 0, this indicates that there are no strong correlations in the repeated measurements of Y within species groups.

Comment: Thanks Dimitris. You quoted "This links to missing data issues, in which case the mixed model, if correctly specified, provides valid inferences under the missing completely at random and missing at random mechanisms." Shuold I do specific things in model formulation to cope with missing data ? Thanks